# Problem with input feature as clipping geometry in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: geometry, arcgis-pro, clip

I am clipping several rasters to the shape of a polygon feature class using the feature class for clipping geometry. However the output looks like this:

[image]

There should be NoData values around the polygon instead of zeros. Any idea about this problem?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.2

Comment: When you say "... I do the same thing in ArcMap it works" is that with exactly the same datasets?

Comment: yes it's with exactly the same datasets.

Comment: I've just run the Clip Raster tool and ticked on the use input features for clipping geometry and it worked as expected. At this point without seeing your system setup and data the only difference between you and me is that I'm running ArcPro 2.4.2, try upgrading?

Comment: Thanks @Hornbydd for your suggestion. I updated to the most recent version of ArcGIS pro but I'm still getting the same result. However, my previous description of the output wasn't fully correct... for the result the tool is "partly" using the polygon shape as clipping geometry. I do see the raster clipped with the polygon but instead of having NoData values outside of the shape of the polygon the rectangle of the polygon extent is filled with zeros. The problem occurs when using the tool directly in ArcGIS Pro and when it is used in a arcpy script (python 3.6.6)

Comment: You may have malformed geometry, this could be especially true if the data has come from some other source, I would run check geometry tool on your data and if it throws up an error repair it?

Comment: Also a picture says a thousand words, suggest you edit your question and shows us the problem with a screen shot...

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is probably a good idea. I checked the geometry but it didn't throw up an error.

Comment: Seems like I figuered it out... the rasters have different NoData values, but I always used the same NoData value in the tool (since I ran it in a loop in arcpy). They all have -128 as NoData value except two have 15 and 65535. Running the tool with -1 for NoData I get the correct result for all the -128 rasters. Before I used -9999 and all rasters were clipped incorrectly. I don't really understand why but at least now I know how to get the result I want...